# Xcode's UI control border width bug

Tags: xcode

Sometimes I'm experiencing weird bug in Xcode. Some of UI controls gets ridiculously thick border which makes them really hard to read.

For example color picker.

[image]

I don't know what triggers this behaviour. After restarting Xcode it's normal again.

Do you know how to fix it? I'm running Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. Just restart Xcode and the issue will be fixed.

It's an Xcode bug. If you want, you can file a bug with Apple to let them know it's an issue.

Comment: Restarting Xcode does not fix the bug. It's recurring.

Comment: Yeah I get that it's Xcode bug but few times I ran into funny solutions to Xcode bugs like deleting some Xcode temporary files, so I was maybe hoping for something like that.

Comment: @Peracek My guess is that it's an internal Xcode bug that doesn't depend on any temporary files. Restarting Xcode does fix it, but only temporarily.